# Защита apache2 от атак dns, как защитить сервер от этих двух уязвимостей? Перепривязка DNS и anti dns pining

Tags: apache2, dns

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /data/edu/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName site.url
    ServerAlias site.url
    Include /etc/apache2/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /data/ssl/u1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /data/ssl/u1.key
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site.url 
    DocumentRoot /data/edu/public
    <Directory /data/edu/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перепривязка DNS и Возможность атаки Anti Dns pining.

Как защитить сервер от этих двух уязвимостей на apache2?

Comment: Вы сами же опубликовали ответ на свой вопрос в этих картинках, в разделах «Как исправить». В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: вообще гуглю вставляю не помогает

Comment: @andreymal я вот вставил код конфига можете посмотреть дать совет я вообще front-end и честно мои знания очень поверхностные